# cakephp get data from db

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp how to write below sql query in cakephp

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '" . $email . "' AND  `password` = '" . $password . "'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

while($fetchdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $fetchdata['name'];
}
```

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: read the cakePHP docs

Comment: why is this even tagged cakephp?

Comment: coz I need to know how to write normal mysql code in cakephp. I mention it on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query:

```
<?php

 $this->loadmodel('User');
 $result = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions' => array('email' => $email,  
 'password' => $password)));
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
   //do whatever you want to do

 }
?>
```

Comment: Your code isn't correct you have miss a ' after User and he wants all result not only first

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I fixed it. And for first/all, please look into the query. For those type of queries, there should be always only one email with password combination. But still there are options to get all, instead of first. I hope I am clear now

Answer (score 2):

In your User controller you can do something like:

```
$this->set('user',$this->User->find('all', array ('conditions' => array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))));
```

And in your view

```
foreach ($user as $us) {
   echo($us['name']);
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

read this for easy authentication with cakephp framework
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Answer (score 1):

Use cakephp `find` method to do that.

```
<?php

    $users = $this->User->find('first',array
    (
        'conditions' => array
        (
            'User.email'    => $email,
            'User.password' => $password
        )
    ));

    pr($users);
    exit;

?>
```

i have added `pr($users);exit;` for debugging result of query.

You can also pass `recursive`, `limit` , `order` etc along with find method read more about `find` at [cakephp](http://cakephp.org)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Users Controller then it is not necessary to load your Model and connect your database. If you access users Model from another Model then load your User Model in your controller. You load your model in two ways

```
$this->loadmodel('User');
or
public $uses = array('User');
$results = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions' => array('email' => $email,'password' => $password)));
$this->set(compact('results '));
```

now in your view file use this

```
foreach ($results as $users) {
  echo h($users['User']['email']);
  echo h($users['User']['password']);
}
```